# A save Remeber Me button? (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I was making a Emailing program, when I came upon the idea of a "Remember Me" setup using a radio button. I was thinking it could save what one has typed in "textbox4","textbox5" and "textbox6". Could this be possible?

EDIT:

My friend had told me this method would work, it doesnt seem to:

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    TextBox4.Text = (TextBox4.Text)
    TextBox5.Text = (TextBox5.Text)
    TextBox6.Text = (TextBox6.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just show us the code where you have problems

Comment: Are you wanting to remember it between uses of the application or just during the current session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you are going to be using RadioButtons's you will need to have more than one of them, a checkbox may be what is needed instead. You can use Project User Settings to persist storage between application uses. You will need to go to your Project Settings Tab and create the Settings, it should look something like this:

[image]

you would implement it something like this

```
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged

        My.MySettings.Default.TextBox4 = TextBox4.Text
        My.MySettings.Default.TextBox5 = TextBox5.Text
        My.MySettings.Default.TextBox6 = TextBox6.Text
        My.MySettings.Default.Save()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        TextBox4.Text = My.MySettings.Default.TextBox4
        TextBox5.Text = My.MySettings.Default.TextBox5
        TextBox6.Text = My.MySettings.Default.TextBox6
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrap what you have been told and try this

use a string variable to hold the data for this session only like this

```
    Dim box1 as string
    Dim box2 as string
    Dim box3 as string

Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged

    Call SaveInput() 
    'OR
    Call SaveInputToFile()
    ' OR BOTH

End Sub

Public Sub Saveinput()

   box1 = TextBox4.Text
   box2 = TextBox5.Text
   box3 = TextBox6.Text 

End Sub
```

if you want to save it to a file for use in other sessions

```
Public Sub SaveinputtoFile()


  Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("FilePath",  False)

    writer.write(TextBox4.Text)
    writer.writeline()
    writer.write(TextBox5.Text)
    writer.writeline()
    writer.write(TextBox6.Text)
    writer.writeline()
    writer.dispose()
```

Comment: Sorry about my huge answer